# Which cards are disallowed in Naxxramas?

Tags: hearthstone

When attempting to use a Doomsayer against the Four Horsemen, Kel'Thuzad admonished me for being clever and destroyed the Doomsayer immediately after I played it.

With which cards does Kel'Thuzad do this against which bosses? Is this the only one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Doomsayer, Kel-Thuzad apparently does not let you play any minion-wiping cards, such as Equality. Source: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Four_Horsemen

Also, Kel'Thuzad will not let you play Alexstrasza against Loatheb, which would make that encounter significantly easier. Source: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loatheb_(hero)

There may be additional restrictions, bearing in mind that 2 more areas are not released yet.